# Focus does not work for Datepicker with validation and mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

MVC4, IE11: There are 2 input fields with Datepicker attached. Those input fields need to have mask for the date: 99/99/9999. And date is validated on the onClose event. If date is invalid, input field need to be cleared and focus set back to it. After invalid date is typed into the input field, on the tab-out-of the field: focus is not set into that input field and focus of both input/datepicker fields goes into some kind of loop, from one to another. Any way: does not work. I am working on this issue for so long, that it's time to ask this question. How to make it all work ? Latest code is below. isDate() is function written by us and returns false if date is invalid. Thank you

.cshtml  file

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap;">Date Range:<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="dateRangeFrom" value="" /> 
to
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="dateRangeTo" value="" />


@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {


    $("#dateRangeFrom").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true            
    }).mask('99/99/9999');

    $("#dateRangeTo").datepicker({ 
            changeMonth: true, 
            changeYear: true
    }).mask('99/99/9999');

});

</script>
}
```

.js  file

```
$("#dateRangeFrom").datepicker({

    /* fix buggy IE focus functionality */
    fixFocusIE: false,

    onClose: function () {

        this.fixFocusIE = true;

        if (!isDate(this.value)) {

            //focus is set to the End of dateRangeTo and stays there 
            // and both fields are flashing yellow background
            $(this).effect("highlight", {}, "medium").val("");
            $(this).focus();

            setTimeout(function () {
                //$("#dateRangeFrom").focus();  //focus is set to the End of dateRangeTo and stays there 
                //$(this).focus();   // focus is Not set back to related input field
            }, 0);
        }
    }, 
    beforeShow: function () {
        var result = $.browser.msie ? !this.fixFocusIE : true;
        this.fixFocusIE = false;
        return result;
    }

});

$("#dateRangeTo").datepicker({

    /* fix buggy IE focus functionality */
    fixFocusIE: false,

    onClose: function () {

        this.fixFocusIE = true;

        if (!isDate(this.value)) {

            //focus is set to the End of dateRangeTo and stays there 
            // and both fields are flashing yellow background
            $(this).effect("highlight", {}, "medium").val("");
            $(this).focus();

            setTimeout(function () {
                //$("#dateRangeTo").focus();  // see comments above
                //$(this).focus();    // focus is Not set back to related input field
            }, 0);
        }            
    }, 
    beforeShow: function () {
        var result = $.browser.msie ? !this.fixFocusIE : true;
        this.fixFocusIE = false;
        return result;
    }

});
```

Comment: providing a jsfiddle would be a 'plus'

Comment: so far mask does not work in jsfiddle

Comment: I will have to include multiple jquery files into jsfiddle to make it work. I will try ...